# Send all incoming and outcoming signals through a SOCKS4 Proxy on terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal, node.js, socks-proxy

So, I am running a node.js app through terminal (namely [bp-tf auto](https://bitbucket.org/srabouin/backpack.tf-automatic) but that isn't relevant) on my laptop. While travelling, I end up going through places where proxies block backpack.tf and connections to/from it. I would like to run all of them through a socks4 proxy. How do I do that?